# Django REST: Get pk of model object in create context

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am in the middle of a project where I am creating a scheduling system for courses. Courses may have a number of sessions. I would like, upon course creation, to create a number of blank sessions (to be scheduled later) equal to a variable in the course request ("class_count"). Each Session has FKs to the user profile and course. The logic I have is something like this:

```
serializer.save(instructor=self.request.user)
for sess in range(int(request.POST.get('class_count'))):
     Session.objects.create(user=self.request.user.profile, session_active=True, course=request)
     Session.save()
```

However, when I do this, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/create/'>": "Session.course" must be a "MyCourse" instance.
```

How would I access the instance of the MyCourse model just created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a MyCourse instance as indicated in the error message. If your serializer data contains a MyCourse instance, you can utilize it. Otherwise, you can retrieve the corresponding MyCourse object using its primary key. (Certainly, you can retrieve a MyCourse instance using other unique field(s) in the model)

```
serializer.save(instructor=self.request.user)
# get course_id somehow
course = MyCourse.objects.get(id=course_id)
for sess in range(int(request.POST.get('class_count'))):
     Session.objects.create(user=self.request.user.profile, session_active=True, course=course)
     Session.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The serializer does contain an instance but I have been unable to find a way to access it. Just tried ```course=serializer.data.get('pk')``` which interestingly gives me a different error (NULL constraint when saving the Session).

Comment: Getting somewhere.``` course = MyCourse.objects.get(pk=serializer.data.get('id'))``` gets past this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, interesting. The solution is twofold. Thanks to Erhan, who gave me the insight I needed. The complete code is:

```
course = MyCourse.objects.get(pk=serializer.data.get('id'))
for sess in range(int(request.POST.get('class_count'))):
    Session.objects.create(user=self.request.user.profile,session_active=True, current_class=course)
```

Access of the MyCourse object is accomplished through `serializer.data.get('id)` and `Session.save()` was not necessary. Thanks to everyone who looked.